# Use *ngif in *ngfor according to amount

Tags: angular

*ngFor I'm going to get the index in it I want to display information until the value is of `i is less than 5` . 
 Here is HTML code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of Items; let i = index ;">
            <ng-container *ngIf="{{i}} > 5">
```

Please suggest appropriate solution for this.

Comment: Hello and welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items | slice:0:10; let i=index"></tr>
```

or

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of Items; let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="i > 5">
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use **`{{}}`** expression while checking against a variable,

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of Items; let i = index ;">
   <ng-container *ngIf="i > 5">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter items list before passing it to the template, for example with simple getter

```
private _allItems = [1, 2, 3 .. 1000];
get itemsForTemplate => _allItems.filter((_, index) => index < 5 && index % 2);
```